# How to List WordPress Pages in checkboxe Options

Tags: wordpress

Can you please let me know how I can load checkboxes based on following code:

```
<?php wp_list_pages('title_li='); ?>
```

I know that this code will list load all pages in wordpress but I would like to have them in checkbox format which let user to select parent for a new product.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function if for creating a *list* of pages as links: [Function_Reference/wp_list_pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages).

So, you need another one: [`get_pages`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages).

```
$mypages = get_pages( array( 
    'sort_column' => 'post_date', 
    'sort_order' => 'desc' 
) );

foreach( $mypages as $page ) 
{       
    $title = $page->post_title;
    $slug = $page->post_name;
    echo "<label>
          <input type='radio' name='the_pages' id='$slug' value='$title'>
          $title
          </label>";
}
```

Comment: Hi brasofilo, Thanks for your comment but this is just returning 4 radio buttons without label(page titles).Do u have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @user1986096, updated the Answer. Those 4 buttons indicate 4 pages, the `radio input` needs a text label as it doesn't output text.